# Accordion does not apply until page load is complete

Tags: jquery, accordion

there is a split second before the page loads that jquery is clearly not applied and the page looks exactly like it does if you disabled javascript. Then when the page is finished loading the jquery kicks in and the accordion looks perfect.

The problem is that it looks really ugly for a split second every time the page is refreshed or navigated to and I have no idea why this happens or how to fix it.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: display:none helps but it seems the main issue is the page load, as Dominic mentioned. Oddly, it loads perfectly in chrome but still shows the accordion bar text without javascript pre-load in ff. Thanks for the comments guys!

Answer (score 4):

Any elements that are not going to be shown in the default accordion view port, should be have the CSS property of display none.

Example:

```
#sampleDiv{

    display:none;
}
```

That should fix the flickering look when the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

Your accordion will probably be run on document ready, this is because your javascript needs to wait for your elements to be loaded to be able to work on them.
So you script will not fire untill every element on your page has loaded, probably your question should be why is my page loading so slowely, are my images to large is my script to big.

Answer (score 1):

What I did, was set `display:none` to the div that has the entire accordion, like this:

```
<div id="accordion" style="display: none;">
        <h3 id="mark">
...
```

Then, in a script tag,

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    var accc = document.getElementById('accordion');
    accc.style.display = "";    
});
```

For the half/full second, instead of showing the incomplete accordion, I just see a blank page, and then the accordion.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer as much as it is some guidance. Accordions are SUPER easy to create with a few lines of basic jQuery. Making your own Accordion will give you MUCH more flexibility and much less overhead. As you can see in my example, the `.accBody` divs (which hold the secondary content) are initialized as hidden so they are never visible until manually expanded.

---

**Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/n55X5/**

---

**CSS**

```
.accHeader{
   padding:2px; 
   background:#000; 
   color:#fff; 
   margin:2px;   
}
.accBody{
 padding:2px;
 display:none;   
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='accHeader'>Header</div>
<div class='accBody'>Body</div>

<div class='accHeader'>Header</div>
<div class='accBody'>Body</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.accHeader').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.accBody').slideToggle('medium');
});
```